# Referenced project's AfterBuild target isn't executed when building parent project

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have 2 projects, a (.Net 4.7) ASP.Net Web API project and a Class Library.

The Web API references the Class Library.

The Class library has the following AfterBuild Target in csproj:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)\Resources\config.json" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\Resources\config.release.json" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)\Resources\config.json" />
  </Target>
```

This works beautifully when building the class lib in debug and release config, to either leave the config or replace it with the release config respectively.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work when I build the Web API project. Regardless of which config I use, it doesn't trigger the AfterBuild when it builds the Class Lib.

Is there a trick, or something I missed to make this work, or is it working as intended?

Edit: Web Api Projectreference from csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ImportLibNet\ImportLibNet.csproj">
      <Project>{5e8d50d2-ce70-4afa-95ed-e182515226a1}</Project>
      <Name>ImportLibNet</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Does it not trigger the build or do you want the config.release.json be also copied to the asp.net web api project? the AfterBuild of the library will only copy to the library's output directory, even when built as a dependency of the api project

Comment: Also, can you show how the files are included in the csproj file? (relevant part of the csproj file)

Comment: It triggers the build, but not the AfterBuild target, so no, it doesn't copy the config file. It DOES copy all of the files just like you'd expect, with all the \Resources\*, but it just doesn't trigger the delete of config.json and replacesment of config.release.json. Updated with reference from parent project's csproj